# Constraintlayout always uses left/right instead of start/end and then instantly shows me a warning

Tags: android, layout

When I use `Constraintlayout` and set the margins with the drag&drop toolkit, it automatically uses `marginleft` and `marginright` and then instantly shows me a warning, that I should consider `marginstart` and `marginend` instead.

Can I somehow set it to automatically using start and end?

I also noticed, that it uses 
`app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"`
instead of `constraintStart_toStartOf`

but for this one it doesn't even show me a warning. However, this tag is not working properly on RTL layouts.

Comment: I think that you have come across an inconsistent use of start/end and left/right in the designer. I have noted the same behavior and seen similar questions on Stack Overflow. I think that this is a bug and may have been reported to Google. If you are interested, you can check the [bug tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).